# ¿Como ingresar una fecha por teclado y usarla en Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tengo una consulta, hice el ejercicio en C pero no se como pasarlo a Python, sobretodo con el tema de cuando introduzco la fecha completa.. Aqui esta el codigo en C

```
#include <stdio.h>

main(){

int DiaN, MesN, AnioN;
int DiaH, MesH, AnioH;
int Dia, Mes, Anio;

printf("Ingrese Dia, Mes y Año de nacimiento (Separados por un espacio): ");
scanf("%d %d %d",&DiaN,&MesN,&AnioN);

printf("Ingrese Dia, Mes y Año del dia de hoy (Separados por un espacio): ");
scanf("%d %d %d",&DiaH,&MesH,&AnioH);

Anio = AnioH - AnioN;

if(MesN > MesH){
    Anio = Anio - 1;
}

Mes = MesH - MesN;

if(Mes < 0){
    Mes = 12 + Mes;
}

if(DiaN > DiaH){
    Mes = Mes - 1;
}

printf("\nAños: %d Meses: %d",Anio,Mes);

}
```

Cualquier ayuda se agradece mucho :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras de hacerlo, la más simple es crear la misma cantidad de variables que en C y luego, ir pidiendo el valor de cada una, algo así sería:

```
# No es necesario el uso del ';' pero bue
print("Ingrese la fecha de nacimiento");
dia1=int(raw_input("Dia: "));
mes1=int(raw_input("Mes: "));
anio1=int(raw_input("Anio: "));
print("\n Ingrese el dia de hoy: ");
# ... y el codigo seguiria mas o menos de ese modo
```

O podrías usar un str para leer la fecha completa y luego separarla en partes, por ejemplo, si yo ingreso dos números separados por un espacio sería algo así:

```
cadena=str(raw_input("Dos numeros separados por un espacio: ")); # Aca tomo los dos numeros
numero1=0;
numero2=0;
cont=0;
while(cadena[cont]!=' '):
    numero1=numero1*10+int(cadena[cont]);
    cont+=1;
cont+=1; 
# Como el cont esta en la posicion de la cadena que tiene un espacio, le sumo 1
while(cont<len(cadena)):
    numero2=numero2*10+int(cadena[cont]);
    cont+=1;
# Aunque esto seria muy largo, puesto que necesitarias 6 bucles mas o menos
```

Con respecto a la otra parte del código, no dista mucho de python, es prácticamente igual, salvo que las llaves no estarían y tendrías que tener en cuenta el indentado y los dos puntos. Por mi parte, te recomiendo la primera opción que te puse, lo otro ya es complicarse al pedo.

Vi mal algo antes, pero ya lo arreglé.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda y por las molestias que se tomo, me ha ayudado mucho con esto pero tengo otra consulta, como haria  printf("\nAños: %d Meses: %d",Anio,Mes);                                                          en python 2.7? lo puse tal cual y me da error en esta linea, desde ya muchas gracias por todo ^^

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres emular un comportamiento similar de cara a usuario al de `scanf` necesitas tres cosas:

- `raw_input()` : para leer la entrada del usuario, retorna una cadena `str` (ASCII en Python 2).
- `str.split()`: permite dividir la cadena usando otra cadena pasada como argumento. Si no se le pasa nada divide usando espacios en blanco, además de eliminarlos del inicio y final de la cadena. Retorna una lista de cadenas.
- `int()`: para hacer un casting a entero de los elementos retornados por `str.split`.

Para aplicar el casting sobre cada item puedes usar un `for in`:

```
entrada = raw_input("Ingrese Dia, Mes y Año de nacimiento"
                    "(Separados por un espacio): ")
dia_n, mes_n, anio_n = (int(item) for item in entrada.split())
```

o puedes usar `map` para usar un enfoque funcional:

```
entrada = raw_input("Ingrese Dia, Mes y Año de nacimiento"
                    "(Separados por un espacio): ")
dia_n, mes_n, anio_n = map(int, entrada.split())
```

En el caso de `printf` puedes usar el viejo formateo con `%` similar al de C:

```
print "Años: %d Meses: %d" % (anio, mes)
```

o usar `str.format`:

```
print "Años: {} Meses: {}".format(anio, mes)
```

En Python 2 el código fuente por defecto usa ASCII, por lo que se debe especificar el encoding adecuado en la primera o segunda línea del script de no ser así. Para usar la `ñ` como tal en el literal de cadena (`print "Años: ..."`) puedes utilizar UTF-8:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

y recuerda guardar el script con esta codificación.

El resto del código no implica más problemas, se puede traducir tal cual a Python con solo cambiar las llaves por la identación adecuada y eliminar los`;` ya que son innecesarios.

---

En Python 3 la idea es la misma, solo que se tiene que substituir `raw_input` por `input` y `print` es una función. Además para Python >= 3.6 se puede (y debe por eficiencia) usar literales de cadena formateados:

```
entrada = input("Ingrese Dia, Mes y Año de nacimiento"
                    "(Separados por un espacio): ")
dia_n, mes_n, anio_n = (int(item) for item in entrada.split())

...

print(f"Años: {anio} Meses: {mes}")
```

En Python 3 el intérprete usa UTF-8 por defecto para el código fuente, por lo que no es necesario especificar el encoding si se usa UTF-8 en el archivo.